# Show array result PHP

Tags: php

How can I get the number '16' in this vardump of my array

```
array(1) { ["COUNT(*)"]=> string(2) "16" } NULL
```

to "echo" it there

**There are *'NUMBER'* users**

In my model there is :

```
public function getCount() {    
    $arrayUser = $this->bdd->getArray('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user');
    $arrayUser = $arrayUser[0];
        var_dump($arrayUser);
}
```

and in my index

```
$countUser = $user->getCount();
var_dump($countUser);
echo 'There are ';
echo ($countUser);
echo ' users';
```

Comment: You are not using `return` in your `getCount();` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function getCount() {    
    $arrayUser = $this->bdd->getArray('SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount FROM user');
    $arrayUser = $arrayUser[0];
    return $arrayUser['amount'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I have to change something in the index page ?

Comment: Most likely not. Try the edited function first ans see if it works. I don't have the same database environment so I can't really test it. But it should work.

Comment: Good to hear. When you want to bring back a value from a function use `return`. That way you can safe it in a different variable when using the function as you are doing here: `$countUser = $user->getCount();`

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT FROM user
```

Then reference it like this

```
$arrayUser[0]['CNT']
```

Comment: Like this ?   $arrayUser = $this->bdd->getArray('SELECT COUNT(*) as CNT FROM user');
  $arrayUser = $arrayUser[0]['CNT'];
   var_dump($arrayUser);

Comment: So what has to change in the index page ?